# Increasing height of tableview in storyboard to accommodate multiple prototype cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I have multiple sections and multiple prototype cells in my tableviewcontroller. The prototype cells combined height exceeds the total height of the view. How can I accommodate all the cells in storyboard? Is there an option to increase the vertical height of the tableview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question. You can scroll the table view in the storyboard to see the rest of the cells.